# Problem creating Oracle database manually

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, installation

I am using Windows 7 and Oracle 11. When I want to create a database manually, it is giving me two problems:

1. I set my `oracle_home` to `c:\app\best\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1`. Under home I have a directory as database, in this directory I want to create the parameter file by edit command it is giving me an error: edit is not recognized as internal or external command. Can any body explain why?
2. Anyhow, I have created the `initfinance.ora` file by edit command in `c:\` directory (here edit command is working) so I created it here and copy it to the database directory under oracle home. Then I set oracle home and set the sid as finance then I want to create the instance so I gave the command `oradim -new -sid finance -startmode manual` 
   here also it has given me the errors (cannot open the windows NT service control manager
   access denied.. and it is not creating my instance please help me out in this situation and one more thing I am running this on my laptop machine only.

Answer (score 1):

1. `edit` was a 16-bit application and 16-bit applications don't run on 64-bit Windows, therefore it is not included in 64-bit Windows.

https://support.microsoft.com/kb/896458

Just use notepad.

2. You should run this with elevated privileges, for example in a command prompt started with "Run as Administrator".